# How to get a bootstrap notice to work with a rails form_for submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a bootstrap notice to appear when someone clicks the submit button for my rails form_for where they are asked if they really want to submit. so far I have been unsuccessful in my many attempts which I have left out of the code below. Any suggestions?

```
                <div class="Action">
                    <%= f.submit "Create Reminder", class: 'btn btn-md btn-primary' %>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="Action">
  <%= f.submit "Create Reminder", class: 'btn btn-md btn-primary', onclick: 'return confirm("Are you sure?");' %>
</div>
```

Or replace confirm with a more intelligent js function that does the same but with better styling.